# SQL Error: Not an Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

More SQLite issues. So my interface is as follows (this is all in .m):

```
@interface Search()
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *databasePath; //path to sqlite database file
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *databaseName;
    @property (nonatomic) sqlite3 *database;
@end
```

and the init follows:

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        self.databaseName = DB_NAME;

        NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        _databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName];
        [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
        if (sqlite3_open_v2([self.databasePath UTF8String], &_database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Missing"
                                       message:@"Database file not found"
                                      delegate:nil
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                             otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%s: sqlite3_open_v2 error: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(self.database));
        }
    }
```

The error that the Log in the init returns is: `sqlite3_open_v2 error: not an error`. In my searches, I've heard that SQLite doesn't return an error when it points to a non-existent database. But I'm not sure why the database wouldn't exist. The copy function I'm using (which I was given and had seemed to work before) is as follows:

```
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase
{
    // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
    BOOL dbExists;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    dbExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_databasePath];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(dbExists)
    {
        return;
    }
    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:_databaseName];

    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    //[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:_databasePath error:nil];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:_databasePath error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"%s: copyItemAtPathError: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
    }
}
```

Finally, I have verified in the iOS Simulator Documents directory that the database exists, and the query I'm trying to execute on it works. Why might I be getting this error?

Comment: Just a thought if you are using lot of SQLite interaction then go for [FMDB Framework](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). Its very lightweight, simple and clean.

Comment: Before I read more into it, does it allow for SQL queries? I am porting a project from Android and the queries are already written.

Comment: 100% it will work.. And its just Objective-C SQLite wrapper. so no issues.

Comment: please refer your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080018/use-and-access-existing-sqlite-database-on-ios) If It works please accept it.

Comment: That could be perfect. I haven't enjoyed working with the SQLite library directly, but I didn't want to take time to write my own library. I guess I should've just looked for one.

Comment: If you'd like, post FMDB as an answer here and I can accept it if it works for me.

Comment: Maybe you should capture and display the SQLite return code.  `SQLITE_OK` is not the only "good" return code.

Comment: I could try that. But if that's the case, what other condition should I check in order to verify that my database is properly opening?

Comment: Check for an error return code.  (Hint: Actually read the documentation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was a very simple one. The object I was trying to assign the values to (and then pull them from) was not initialized. It was a very silly oversight on my part, but I'm still new to Objective C.

Additionally, I do recommend icodebuster's suggestions to use FMDB for SQLite in iOS. It cleaned up some of my SQLite mess and made it a lot nicer to use.

Answer (score 3):

Having never worked with SQLLite like this, I only want to mention, that in the code above, your  else statement gets called, when `sqlite_open_v2 == SQL_OK`. So maybe in that case, there is just no error to return and everything is fine?!

Comment: So what would be a better condition to check? The reason I'm asking this question is because I wouldn't have noticed the error except that getting incorrect results from my query led me to check my log output, which is where I found this error.

Comment: @rar Your `if` check on `sqlite2_open_v2` is fine. The problem is the `else`. The `else` is reached when the database is properly opened. So there is no error. The log statement is showing exactly what it should - there is no error. You have confused yourself into thinking there is a problem where there is none.

Comment: Been away and I totally agree with @rmaddy - there seems to be no error and the if is fine - you just confused yourself there

Comment: Well the reason I think there's a problem with this is because my query is returning no results, despite returning the destined results when I try it directly on the database myself. So I noticed this error and that's why I suspected it might be an issue. I might have to check elsewhere, though, thanks.