# Sqlite Database query on iOS only updates one field

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have been reading all the answers of sqlite update query but mine isn't working.

It only updates the "categoria" column but not the "user comments"

"categoria" is the last Column of my Sqlite Database but i have a lot more columns that im not updating, does this affect my query? should I update every column although im not updating them?

here is my code:

```
NSString *query =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE apps set userComment='%@', categoria='%@'   WHERE id='%d'",app.userComment, app.categoria, [[app appID] intValue]];

     sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_dataBase, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)
        == SQLITE_OK)
    {

         NSLog(@"error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_dataBase));

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_dataBase));
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"updateContact SUCCESS - executed command %@",query);
        }
        sqlite3_reset(statement);
        sqlite3_step(statement);
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

           // sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_dataBase));
```

The NSLog of my query seems right , and i´m not getting any error !! 
I don´t know whats going on..
Please help!
Thanks!!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Use the sqlite3 command line tool to dump the DB.  Does the "apps" table actually contain a "userComment" column??

Comment: @bryanmac thanks a lot, the problem was on the SELECT and INSERT methods, i was confused with the binding column, i marked your answer as correct thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting quotes around an int value:

```
WHERE id='%d' ... [[app appID] intValue]
```

Use params (?) and bind an int/int64 to avoid that:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 3, [[app appID] intValue]);
```

In your sqlite3_step call, make sure you check check for done.

```
if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE)
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@", sqlite3_errmsg(_dataBase));
}
```

NSLog out your update statement.  Ensure it actually has the userComment value you think it should.

Use params ? for values and use bind and use UTF8String:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [[app userComment] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

Since sqlite3 is a C API, you should probably use NULL and not nil in your prepare statement.

Printing our sqlite3_errmsg after OK prepare call is not needed.  More interesting to check after reset, step.

As reference, see my code in this answer:

[how to save the data in sqlite3 in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592844/how-to-save-the-data-in-sqlite3-in-iphone/17593881#17593881)

That post has update code that I know works.

Answer (score 2):

try param.

```
- (void) update
{
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(updateStatement == nil)
        {
            const char *sql = "UPDATE apps set userComment = ?, categoria = ? WHERE id = ?";
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, & updateStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }

        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStatement, 1, [comment UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStatement, 2, [categoria UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int(updateStatement, 3, id);


        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStatement))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        else
            //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
            //noteID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

            //Reset the update statement.
            sqlite3_reset(updateStatement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
        deleteStatement = nil;
    }
    else
        sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: This works too, i just saw the previous answer firts, Thanks a lot.. !

Answer (score 0):

I have simple solution to work with Update query. Now you don't need to use sqlite3_bind_text or sqlite3_bind_int.

Just use update query as normal query and pass parameters in query as we pass in string using '%@'

Here is sample query

```
queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE <Table-name> SET <column-name> = '%@', <column-name2> = '%@';", value1, value2];

if (sqlite3_prepare(contactDB, query, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{

}

if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
{
     //NSLog(@"ok");
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

After using above code you will be able to run update query. Hope it'll help someone.

Comment: what about the WHERE part?

Comment: The above query is an example of using Update query, we can change the query according to our requirements.