# Select from database where date = today

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite, nsdateformatter

I have a table in an sqlite database which has a variable of date. I have set up a function that tells me what the date is on that day in this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[self.dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[self.dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
_todayDate = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

I then make an sql statement that uses the date:

```
-(void) readRecordsFromDatabaseWithPath:(NSString *)filePath {

    sqlite3 *database;

    if (sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sqlStateMent = "select * from records where date = ?";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        NSLog(@"%d", sqlite3_prepare(database, sqlStateMent, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL));
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStateMent, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [_todayDate UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *recordid = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                NSString *patientid = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                NSString *treatmentid = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                NSString *date = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
                NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];
                NSString *area = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 5)];
                NSString *level = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 6)];
                NSString *shots = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 7)];
                Record *newRecord = [[Record alloc] init];
                newRecord.patientid = patientid;
                newRecord.recordid = recordid;
                newRecord.treatmentid = treatmentid;
                newRecord.date = date;
                newRecord.name = name;
                newRecord.area = area;
                newRecord.level = level;
                newRecord.shots = shots;
                LSAppDelegate *delegate = (LSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                [delegate.records addObject:newRecord];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Then finally call the function:

```
NSString *filePath = [self copyDatabaseToDocuments];
[self readRecordsFromDatabaseWithPath:filePath];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

I'm sorry for the vast amount of code though I am quite new to objective-c and normally people want to see some code.

Comment: And what is your question? Anyway, the likely answer is that the formats of the date values do not match.

Comment: do u want all the records whose date is "Today"? if yes see my answer.

Comment: @ollie-cole This comment is not related to your question. I would suggest you to used [FMDB Framework](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) for all your database operations. You may refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17268032/1017893)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it myself and then checked on each date if it was equal to a string and if it was then add it to the array

Answer (score 0):

The above code will give you the current date

```
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    formatter.timeZone = destinationTimeZone;
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString* dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSLog(@"tha date is..%@",dateString);
```

and your select Query will be like this

```
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from records where date ='%@'", dateString];
const char *sqlStateMent = [queryString UTF8String];
```

Comment: I see where your going and followed it though it came to nothing. I nslogged the sqlstatement then copied it into terminal ran it then it came up with some results which is really weird can you think whats wrong?