# SQLite database not saving on iOS

Tags: ios, sql, database, sqlite

I am updating an entry in a database, the statement works and the code is updated in the database. Once the app has been closed and reopened though the database has not saved. It seems to create a temporary database and then not actually save to the database that the app is reading from.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)updateDatabase:(int)Level andPlayer:(int)questionID{
    DataClass *obj=[DataClass getInstance];
    //NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString* Database =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"levelProgress.db"];
    NSString* databaseP = [[[NSBundle          mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:Database];
databasePath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:databaseP];

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &questionDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE levelProgress SET completed_questions=completed_questions+1 WHERE level=%d", obj.levelSelected];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(questionDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE){
        NSLog(@"update worked");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"did not work");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(questionDB);
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't update a read-only file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy database file `databaseP` from application bundle into user folder and then update that. You can't update any file in application bundle (they are always read only).

```
#define kDatabaseName (@"levelProgress.db")
- (void)checkAndCopyDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    if (!self.databasePath)
    {
        // Database should be present in user sandbox at root.
        self.databasePath = [NSString pathWithComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject], kDatabaseName, nil]];
    }

    // Check if the file already copied/exists.
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.databasePath];

    if(!success)
    {
        // Copy the file from app bundle to user sandbox (Files in app bundle can not be edited).

        NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDatabaseName];

#if DEBUG
        BOOL isCopied =
#endif
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:self.databasePath error:nil];

        NSAssert(isCopied, @"Problem copying database file to user document folder");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much for this, once the file is in the user documents directory, can the user see the file that I put in there? If they can, can you prevent them from seeing the content of the files?

Comment: This file is copied in Documents directory of app sandbox and it's reasonably secure. On non-jailbroken phone, no-one else except your app can access this file. Read the official documents here (Particularly - "The App Sandbox" section) - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html

Comment: Should the database not be in Library/Application Support. Having it in documents directory will let users have access to the file. My Sqlite Db is a writeable file but has no meaning to the user.

Comment: If you enable 'UIFileSharingEnabled' in your plist, this will allow users to download the SQLite database in the path above. Storing it with the location 'NSLibraryDirectory' would avoid exposing the database to users.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1699/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

When the database is in the bundle it is read only. You will need to have your database in your documents directory when writing to it!

Have a look at the accepted answer here: [Use and Access Existing SQLite Database on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080018/use-and-access-existing-sqlite-database-on-ios)