# Annotation pins and detail view from sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, mapkit

I've been looking around the Internet to find a tutorial or something to explain this.

I need to show some pins on a map. I need to get them from a sqlite database (table with POI's name, lat, lon, and some text). They have to show annotations callouts with title and subtitle and open their detail views.

All that with Objective-C.

How can I do that? Can anybody help and write the code?

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with? Is it getting things from the sqlite db or is it creating the annotations or adding them to a map and displaying the map?

Comment: first of all getting them from the sqlite db and show them on the map. then making them open the appropriate detail view (object at index kinda thing)

Comment: Where is the sqlite db? How do you put things in there? Answering that might also answer how to get things out of the db.

Comment: db file is in the app's resources folder

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to get files from a local sqlite db. [This stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17268032/1857279) is pretty helpful in getting started on that. It might take an hour to get up to speed on it, but you'll save that hour many times over once you're comfortable with it.

Now that you're able to retrieve data from your db, you need to create `MKAnnotation`s for each pin you want to drop on the map. [This tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-drop-a-pin-on-map-with-mapkit-api/) is pretty short and to the point for what you're looking for. Also, don't worry about adding a lot of annotations, `MapKit` is optimized for have a large number of annotations on a map.

Lastly, you want to be able to go from an annotation to a detail view. `MKAnnotationView` has a property called `leftCalloutAccessoryView` where you can add a button. If you just want a quick and dirty fix, set the `tag` property on the button to the index in the array with the info for the detail view and have every button call the same selector.

Comment: As far as retrieving datas from sqlite and creating a map I'm fine. I can't put the to things together though. How can I tell the annotation to show a pin on the map according to the coordinates from a certain row in the database?

Comment: Are you able to get the coordinates from the SQLite db into another data type, eg `NSString`, `float`, `NSDictionary`?

Comment: In the Table View .m file I get datas like this:  NSString *title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 2)];
then in the prepareForSegue: destViewController.dataName = [listOfTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: And when you log out `title` what do you see? Is it usable data yet?