# How can i use existing DB.sqlite from folder in swift project?

Tags: ios, swift2, fmdb

I know about `FMdb` and use it to my project, but I don't know how use existing DB file and where can I add my `DB.sqlite` in my project?

Comment: Refer link http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/use-sqlite-database-swift

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080018/use-and-access-existing-sqlite-database-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

1. drop "DB.sqlite" to your project folder (in navigation window)
2. add following code to your AppDelegate.swift file

   ```
       func checkDataBase(){
   print("check database...")//log
   let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("DB.sqlite")
   // Load the existing database
   if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(url.path!) {
       print("Not found, copy one!!!")//log         
       let sourceSqliteURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("DB", withExtension: "sqlite")!
       let destSqliteURL = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("DB.sqlite")        
       do {
           try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(sourceSqliteURL, toURL: destSqliteURL)
       } catch {
           print(error)
       }           
   }else{
   print("DB file exist")//log
   }}
   ```

3.Function is ready to use, just call "checkDataBase()" function in "func application" maybe..