# Connect to bundled database with FMDB

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, fmdb

I added a `SQLite` database to my bundle via

- Drag and Drop into XCode
- Create groups
- Add to target (PROJECTNAME)

I then try to access the database

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mbtiles"];
NSLog(@"%@", path);
```

> /Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4AB0090D-6035-4C78-90F3-CD6B70D81F05/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/721198C0-FFD8-42B1-9C79-78DBC54AB644/maps.app/test.mbtiles

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
[db open];
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM maps"];
```

So far everything seems good. At least I am not getting any errors/warnings.

```
NSLog(@"%@", rs);
```

> FMResultSet: 0x604000a5f380

```
NSDictionary *dict = [rs resultDictionary];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

> Warning: There seem to be no columns in this set.

```
NSData *tile = [databaseResult dataForColumn:@"tile_data"];
```

> (null)

Why is that? Is it not possible to access a database that is saved in the bundled ressources?

I try to check for existens of database with this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17080018/use-and-access-existing-sqlite-database-on-ios?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.mbtiles"];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appDBPath];
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.mbtiles"];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:appDBPath error:&error];
```

> open on /Users/.../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4AB0090D-6035-4C78-90F3-CD6B70D81F05/data/Containers/Data/Application/EB9390A7-2210-4C8A-A94A-016C03FA1296/Documents/test.mbtiles: File exists

That tells me that the `database` is there if I am not mistaken?!
However, when I try something like

```
NSAssert(success, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
```

> *** Assertion failure in -[DatabaseAccess loadTileAtPath:result:], /Users/.../DatabaseAccess.m:78

I am a little lost here. Why can't I query my `database`?

Comment: Have you ticked the copy?

Answer (score 0):

Even if one expects only a result with *one* row, the `next` statement is needed.

```
FMResultSet *s = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM myTable"];
while ([s next]) {
    //retrieve values for each record
}
```

You must always invoke `-[FMResultSet next]` before attempting to access the values returned in a query, even if you're only expecting one:

```
FMResultSet *s = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable"];
if ([s next]) {
    int totalCount = [s intForColumnIndex:0];
}
```

Source: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#executing-queries